# Fails to perform all CRUD operations except GET request (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman, crud

I'm currently working on a small beginners educational project, a small computers website where you can add, edit or delete computers. As the title suggests, I can only GET all of the computers on my website, and GET an individual computer by it's id, but other requests (POST, PUT, DELETE) are not working, Postman "Could not get response". The most confusing thing is that I followed a tutorial step by step, and my code seems identical to the one on the video, but yet mine fails.

Where do I need to look to find the issue? Maybe it fails to save the new computer into the DB? The body of the request is valid, and is 100% identical to the request body inside the tutorial, same goes with the code for the POST request itself. So i'm pretty sure I have to look elsewhere to find my answer, but I don't know where to look.

Here is my POST request:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult PostComputer(ComputerDto computerDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

            var computer = Mapper.Map<ComputerDto, Computer>(computerDto);

            _context.Computers.Add(computer);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            computerDto.Id = computer.Id;

            return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + computerDto.Id), computerDto);
        }
```

Comment: Is your model valid , otherwise it will return BadRequest.

Comment: Seems like it's valid. Even if I comment out the `If (!ModelState.IsValid)` line it still fails

Comment: Try debugging the code , are you able to catch ComputerDTO correctly? Also try specifying route attribute in other requests